# Repeated measures plot: overlay mean trajectory and error bars (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series, longitudinal

I have made two plots of some repeated measures scores. The first plot is of individuals scores (i.e., scores for each participant are plotted). The second is a plot of mean scores and error bars. I want to combine these two plots so that the second plot overlays the first, or add the mean trajectory and error bars to the first plot. How can this be done?

Example data and the code for creating the plots are below.

[image]

[image]

**CODE**

```
# Renames variables for reshaping  
names(data_wide) [names(data_wide) == "score.baseline"] <- "score.0"
names(data_wide) [names(data_wide) == "score.wave1"] <- "score.1"
names(data_wide) [names(data_wide) == "score.wave2"] <- "score.2"
names(data_wide) [names(data_wide) == "score.wave3"] <- "score.3"

#Convert wide-formatted data into long  
data_long <- reshape(as.data.frame(data_wide), 
                             idvar="ID", 
                             varying=c("score.0", "score.1", "score.2", "score.3"),
                             direction="long")

# Prepare means data

data_long.group <- data_long %>% 
                    group_by(time) %>% 
                    summarise(
                    score_mean = (mean(score, na.rm=TRUE)),
                    score_sd = (sd(score, na.rm=TRUE))
                    ) 

# Plot individual scores

ggplot(data_long, aes(x = factor(time), y = score, color = as.factor(ID), group = ID)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.2) + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  labs(title = "Trajectories", y = "data score", x = "Wave") 

# Plot group-level means and SDs 

ggplot(data_long.group, aes(x = time, y = score_mean)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.2) + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  labs(title = "Trajectories", y = "data score", x = "Wave") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=score_mean-score_sd, ymax=score_mean+score_sd), width=.2,
                 position=position_dodge(0.05))
```

**EXAMPLE DATA**

```
data_wide <- structure(
    list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
    score.baseline = c(4, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4), 
    score.wave1 = c(3.5, 5.67, 5.33, 4, 6.67, 4.5), 
    score.wave2 = c(4, 5, NA, 4, 6.67, 4), 
    score.wave3 = c(6, 6, 4.67, 4.33, 6.67, 3)), 
    row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
    class = c("data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to combine the codes. However, since aesthetics are inherited inside a single ggplot call, you have to `NULL`ify those that are not needed in the respective layer

```
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = factor(time), 
                      y = score, 
                      color = as.factor(ID),
                      group = ID)) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.2) + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  labs(title = "Trajectories", y = "data score", x = "Wave") +
  geom_line(data = data_long.group,
            mapping = aes(x = time,
                          y = score_mean,
                          group = NULL, 
                          color = NULL),
            size = 0.2) + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  labs(title = "Trajectories", y = "data score", x = "Wave") +
  geom_errorbar(data = data_long.group, 
                mapping = aes(ymin = score_mean - score_sd,
                              ymax = score_mean + score_sd,
                              y = NULL,
                              group = NULL,
                              color = NULL),
                width = .2,
                position = position_dodge(0.05))
```

[image]